# Are there NAS / Docks that supports SanDisk Extreme Pro SSD?

Tags: ssd, raspberry-pi, nas

I was looking at NAS and they are all supporting bulky and slow SATA disks or even if it's SSDs, it looks like they're targeting lower speed ones (~500 MB/s) like https://www.windowscentral.com/best-ssd-nas

Newer SSDs like SanDisk supports up to 2 GB/s through USB. **Are there NAS that supports SanDisk Extreme Pro SSD?**

If I were to setup an [8GB RAM raspberry pi](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/) + plug in a dangling portable extreme pro ssd, would that work? Anyone know of a good guide for for that?

Or is there some usb-c docks for multiple harddisk that holds multiples extreme pro ssds? So that I can just duct tape the raspberry pi with a case to the dock and make it my own NAS?

Comment: You don't need a "NAS" like a Synology or QNAP if you don't need RAID (protecting your data from drive failure). You can share a USB storage device from your desktop or even most routers that have a USB port. The software that those boxes can run is convenient but even with the shared folder approach there are alternative ways to get the same features. A RPi with the SSD attached would make a decent "NAS" but I wouldn't count on something like that for data protection.

Comment: You would need to research the RPI's throughput in YOUR use case. Often the network is the bottleneck, and then what is the advantage of super fast (expensive) storage?... probably nothing.  :-)  FYI some NAS info : https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/15420/17251